# How to interpreting the exponential coefficent in poisson regression with offset?

Tags: logistic-regression

I am trying to find the village level risk factors for malaria. Therefore, I ran a poisson model in r with the prevalence of malaria(y) as dependent variable, altitude(x1) and Forestation(x2) as independent variable and log of Population(x3) as offset.

```
glmer(y~x1+x2+(1|cluster), family = poisson, offset = log(x3))
```

From what I have read, I understand that the interpretation of model with offset is different than a non-offset model.

It would be very helpful, If any one can clear the air on how to interpret the coefficients and exponential coefficient in the above-mentioned case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offset means "exposure", so when you are calculating a regression with offset, instead of calculating absolute values, you are calculating ratios.

You are changing "number of thefts" for "number of thefts for every 10.000 vehicles"

$y = x1+x2+(1|cluster) + log(x_3)$: This is the equation you are calculating.

I think you are missing a log in $y$ because the offset and the endogenous variable have to form a ratio:

$log(y) = x1 + x2+(1|cluster)+log(x_3)$

$log(y)-log(x_3) = x1 + x2+(1|cluster)$

$log(\frac{y}{x_3}) = x1 + x2+(1|cluster)$

$log(ratio) = x1 + x2+(1|cluster)$

Comment: Thank you Juan, from your answer what I understand is that the exponential coefficient of x1 will be the times change in prevalence of y(and not y) with change in 1 unit of x1. RIght?

Comment: So , incase the exponential coefficient is say 3.21 for x1 then i can say that the prevalence of malaria will rise by 3.21 times with increase of i unit in x1 keeping all other covariates fixed. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: It would be helpful if you update your answer with the answers to my comments. How the interpretation of outcome changes with the use of offset.